# What do the red dashed lines mean in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

What are the red/white "dotted" lines signifying in Google Maps?  See image:

[image: red and white dots around perimeter of the island Aneityum]

See also [Aneityum on Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/yAJDHeS28hsamxx36).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147771/discussion-on-question-by-cptbeyond-colored-lines-in-google-maps); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate [What does a pink area with dashed lines mean on Google Maps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/24175/881639) (Google changed the color of the line, but the explanation is the same) Related help article [Use layers to find places, traffic, terrain, biking & transit](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3092439?hl=en) and related blog article about the color / design changes [Google Maps gets a new look](https://blog.google/products/maps/google-maps-gets-new-look/)